# Randomized algorithm not behaving as expected

Tags: algorithm, haskell, random

I am implementing an approximate counting algorithm where we:

Maintain a counter *X* using log (log *n*) bits

- Initialize *X* to 0
- When an item arrives, increase *X* by 1 with probability (½)<sup>*X*</sup>
- When the stream is over, output 2<sup>*X*</sup> − 1 so that E[2<sup>*X*</sup>]= *n* + 1

My implementation is as follows:

```
import System.Random

type Prob   = Double
type Tosses = Int

-- * for sake of simplicity we assume 0 <= p <= 1
tos :: Prob -> StdGen -> (Bool,StdGen)
tos p s = (q <= 100*p, s')
  where (q,s') = randomR (1,100) s

toses :: Prob -> Tosses -> StdGen -> [(Bool,StdGen)]
toses _ 0 _ = []
toses p n s = let t@(b,s') = tos p s in t : toses p (pred n) s'

toses' :: Prob -> Tosses -> StdGen -> [Bool]
toses' p n = fmap fst . toses p n

morris :: StdGen -> [a] -> Int
morris s xs = go s xs 0 where
  go _ []     n = n
  go s (_:xs) n = go s' xs n' where
    (h,s') = tos (0.5^n) s 
    n'     = if h then succ n else n

main :: IO Int
main = do
  s <- newStdGen
  return $ morris s [1..10000]
```

The problem is that my X is always incorrect for any `|stream| > 2`, and it seems like for all `StdGen` and `|stream| > 1000`, `X = 7`

I tested the same algorithm in Matlab and it works there, so I assume it's either

1. an issue with my random number generator, or
2. raising 1/2 to a large n in `Double`

Please suggest a path forward?

Comment: If it works in Matlab, it couldn't be a algorithms issue. I don't know what language this is, but you should post in that stackoverflow

Comment: Your mathy symbols do not show up well on my phone. Could you use ASCII, or at least more commonly available symbols?

Comment: Indeed `0.5^2000 :: Double` is zero, but I can't see if this can cause trouble here.

Comment: This is _not_ your problem, but note that passing `StdGen` around like this is error-prone, since it's easy to use an old one, or use a new one twice. That being said, your code seems to be correctly passing them around, as far as I can see. To prevent these kinds of traps, in the future, consider using a monad like `Rand` from `Control.Monad.Random`.

Comment: dfeuer I just did. and @chi if I was passing stdGen around would using Rand make a difference?

Comment: @chibro2 No difference, AFAICT. It's just a different style, but the semantics would be the same.

Comment: @chi ok I'll do that. But unfortunately this subtle bug is still eluding me

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is actually very simple: with `randomR (1,100)` you preclude values within the first percent, so you have a complete cutoff at high powers of 1/2 (which all lie in that small interval). Actually a general thing: [*ranges should start at zero*](https://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/EWD/transcriptions/EWD08xx/EWD831.html), not at one<sup>†</sup>, unless there's a specific reason.

But why even use a range of 100 in the first place? I'd just make it

```
tos :: Prob -> StdGen -> (Bool,StdGen)
tos p s = (q <= p, s')
  where (q,s') = randomR (0,1) s
```

---

<sup>†</sup><sub>I know, Matlab gets this wrong all over the place. Just one of the [many](http://www.parallelnetz.de/ScriptingHater.html) horrible things about that language.</sub>

---

Unrelated to your problem: as chi remarked this kind of code looks a lot nicer if you use a suitable random monad, instead of manually passing around `StdGen`s.

```
import Data.Random
import Data.Random.Source.Std

type Prob   = Double

tos :: Prob -> RVar Bool
tos p = do
  q <- uniform 0 1
  return $ q <= p

morris :: [a] -> RVar Int
morris xs = go xs 0 where
  go []     n = return n
  go (_:xs) n = do
    h <- tos (0.5^n)
    go xs $ if h then succ n else n

morrisTest :: Int -> IO Int
morrisTest n = do
  runRVar (morris [1..n]) StdRandom
```

Comment: now is there a way to generalize the signature of `tos`, ie `MonadState Int m => m Int` vs `State Int Int` ? I can't seem to find some `MonadRVar`

Comment: @chibro2: you can always use [`lift`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-Class.html#v:lift) to reach into a transformer stack on top of `RVal`, or you can use `RValT` itself on top of the stack.